# Rhythmbox does not add mp3 files from NTFS partition

Tags: ntfs, rhythmbox, 16.04

ubuntu 16.04 x64
I installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Rhythmbox plays the file if it is picked from ext4 partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question really lacks detail, so if this does not help, please provide extra detail.

It seems like you don't have executable permissions on the NTFS drive (this is default behavior) so it can't execute the files on the partition.

Open the application `Disks` from the dash and click the drive on the left, now click the small cog icon under the diagram [image] and choose `Edit mount options`.

Turn off `Automatic mount options` and check `mount at start up`

[image]

Click OK and reboot, now the drive is mounted with permissions for your user and you can import and play the music from that drive.